# Обработка выборки - модель или контроллер?

Tags: mvc, php

Добрый день,

Работаем с opencart, получаем выборку из БД, появляется потребность сделать следующее:

1. пройтись по строкам и немного отформатировать под вывод;
2. добавить ссылки при помощи дефолтной библиотеки.

Код, который получаем в модели:

```
    $query = $this->db->query("
        // мой запрос
    ");
    $result = array();
    $tmp = "";
    foreach ($query->rows AS $row) {
        if ($tmp == $row['country_name']) {
            unset ($row['country_name']); // потом в виде будет if(isset($row['country_name'])) { ...
        } else {
            $tmp = $row['country_name'];
        }
        $row['link'] = $this->url->link("football/tournament", "tournament_id=".$row['league_id']); // стандартная библиотека
        $result[] = $row;
    }

    return $result;
```

Собственно, вопрос: по-православному ли делать эти пасы в модели, или же таки в контроллере нужно? Где должна проходить преобработка данных, и ежели таки в модели - то для чего нам контроллеры вне ядра?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Контроллеры обрабатывают данные приходящие от пользователя, логика сайта тоже тут, все выборки из базы делаются посредством вызова функции модели.
В вашем случае это работа с базой должна быть в модели, а функция вызывающая в контроллере.

Comment: а преобработка выборки?

Comment: простите, а "функция вызывающая" - это что за идиома? )

Comment: Допустим есть модель, которая работает с базой юзеров, он выдергивает логин по айди:

    class User(){
        function getLogin($id){
            return $db->select("SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `id`={$id}");
        }
    }

А вот контроллер, где происходит фильтрация `$_GET['id']`, вот тут `User::getLogin` это и есть вызывающая функция

    Class Main(){
        function __construct(){
            $_GET['id'] = intval($_GET['id']);
            $this -> user = User::getLogin($_GET['id']);
        }
    }